# Problems with Sqoop import-all-tables command

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sqoop, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to import all the tables from several SQL Server databases into HDFS using Sqoop. I am using Cloudera CDH 5.7. So I type the following command:

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://X.X.X.X:1433;database=FEPDB" --username XXXXX --password XXXXX --hive-import
```

It runs successfully but all the tables present in the 'FEPDB' Database are not being imported. I don't find them in the hive directory in the HDFS or when I list all the tables present in Hive.

So I tried to import all the tables into a directory in HDFS and then create hive tables. I gave the following command:

```
   sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://X.X.X.X:1433;database=FEPDB" --username XXXXX --password XXXXX --target-dir "/user/FEPDB"
```

It gives me an error saying

> unrecognized argument --target-dir

Doesn't --target-dir argument work with import-all-tables command? And why are all the tables from a database not being imported in the first place? Is there a way to get past these errors and import all the tables in a much easier way?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That is not the problem. I have already tried that.

Answer (score 1):

import-all-tables expect parameter with --warehouse-dir, provide warehouse-dir and hdfs path, it will work

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. I have given the following command:
sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://X.X.X.X:1433;database=FEPDB" --username xxxx --password xxxx --hive-import --warehouse-dir "User/hive/warehouse/FEPDB"

the directory I have mentioned in the --warehouse-dir argument is empty.

Comment: What's error? Did you provided --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-database dbname --hive-home /user/hive/warehouse, Eventhough --hive-home is not mandatory.. but put the actual error..

Comment: I didn't get any error when I ran it. Its just that the directory i mentioned as the --warehouse-dir is empty. I'll try the other arguments that you mentioned.

Comment: Is it just hanging during hive import? or it is completing without an error?

Comment: It is running perfectly fine.

Comment: Which means loading data?

Comment: It is doing all the map and reduce operations of loading the data. There is no error in that process. But after all the process is complete, I dont find the data(Tables).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: sqoop import-all-tables --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://X.X.X.X:1433;database=FEPDB" --username XXXXX --password XXXXX --warehouse-dir

Comment: Tried that. But it doesn't work. import-all-tables has some conditions that must be met for it to import all the tables from a database. I guess It's better to import each table one by one.

Comment: I found that it is better to upload individual tables one by one as import-all-tables command has some conditions that should be satisfied by all the tables in a database.

Comment: @HemanthAnnavarapu, it depends on your requirement. If the requirement is to import only few tables then yes your approach is correct. But, let's say you have to import all tables then import-all-tables.